# Why does a sequence in $\ell^2$ always converge to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was taking the MOOC on Functional Analysis offered on coursera and in one of the videos in which the professor gives an example of  a sequence which converges in the weak topology but not in the strong topology, he gives an example of an $\ell^2$ sequence

$(u_k)=\delta_{kn}$

$u_1=\{1,0,0,...\}$

$u_2=\{0,1,0,...\}$

He then defines the product $\langle u_k,v\rangle$ where $v \in \ell^2$ and claims that

$\lim_{k \to \infty}\langle u_k,v\rangle=0$ as $v_k$ is convergent to zero.
I do not understand why all the sequences in $\ell^2$ converge to zero.

Comment: If they don't, they're not in $l^2$

Comment: @user3503589 check the requirements for membership in $\ell^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's suppose we have some sequence of terms $a_k.$ Now, in order for the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$$ to converge, we must have that $a_k\to 0$ as $k\to\infty,$ by the Cauchy convergence condition.

If, on the other hand, we have a sequence of terms $b_k,$ and we know that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2$$ converges, then by the above, we know that $b_k^2\to 0$ as $k\to\infty.$ But this can only happen if $b_k\to0$ as $k\to\infty.$ Hence, every $\ell^2$ sequence converges to $0,$ by definition of $\ell^2$ and the above remarks.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but I still do not follow. An element of a sequence in $l^2$ is a sequence in $R$ which converges to zero by the definition that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {a_k}^2$ is finite for some element $a_n$ of the sequence $(a_k)$ but I do not see why the any sequence sequence $(a_k)$ should converge $0$ ie $(0,0...)$

Comment: There is no reason why a sequence of elements of $\ell^2$ should converge at all, much less to the zero sequence. Every *element* of $\ell^2$ is itself a sequence that converges to $0.$ Additionally, it makes no sense to say "$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2$ is finite for some element $a_n$ of the sequence $(a_k)$...." Can you clarify what you're trying to say, there? That may be part of the confusion.

Comment: I thought that a sequence in $\ell^2$ converging to zero meant that if we take any sequence(of sequences) , they converged to the sequence of zeros ie $(0,0....)$. It is clear to me that if we pick an element in $\ell^2$ which is a sequence and it would converge to $0$ due to the reasons you explained above

Comment: Not at all. Consider the sequence $x=(2^{-n}).$ This is readily an element of $\ell^2.$ Now consider the sequence $(x_k)$ with each $x_k=x.$ Clearly, this converges, but not to the zero sequence. Furthermore, the sequence $(u_k)$ from your post doesn't converge *at all* in the topology induced by the inner product.

Comment: Thank you Cameron, I understand now. The $v_k$ where k was an index of a sequence  $v$ in $\ell^2$ which I thought was a sequence and therefore I was confused. I am sorry but there was a typo , $u_2=(0,1,0,.....)$. Thank you for clearing up the confusion

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help. (I had trouble with the whole "sequences of sequences" thing, too, when I was getting started.)